# How to make responsive column view with min-height div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having the issue with a variable height on my div 
which is not allowing div to position on the appropriate place

I have added a problem as a code snippet to play with.

Here is the solution that I want:

[image]

Note:
 div has variable height so I can not remove min-width property

I wanted to make it responsive so for different devices it will have a different column, so I can not use like following way( Html class hierarchy )

```
Row

  Column

  Column

Row

  Column
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="min-height: 400px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="min-height: 200px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="min-height: 200px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css flex boxes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    
    .column {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="min-height: 400px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="min-height: 200px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="min-height: 200px; background:#bfaeae; border: 1px dotted;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,
Here "column 2" has a height of 200px still it goes to 400px ?

Comment: you wanted them to have a different height?

Comment: Navin, try to use flexbox and grid to make the pages.